# glossaries vs hyperref conflict

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, incompatibility

I'm writing my thesis and I'm having some trouble with the package [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries) and some strange conflict with [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/) package.
If I load `hyperref` before `glossaries` in order to have links I cannot compile:

```
Overfull \hbox (7.93062pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 16--17
[]\T1/pplj/m/n/12 compares the clas-si-fi-ca-tion and com-pu-ta-tional
per-for- mance ) [6] (./Thesis.gls ! Undefined control sequence.
\@hyper@@anchor ...: #2#3}\else \def \anchor@spot 
                                                  {#2#3}\let \put@me@back \@... l.6         \setentrycounter{page}\glsnumberformat{15}}}
                                                  % ?
```

If I load `hyperref` after `glossaries`, everything is fine but of course I cannot have links.

I'm pretty sure it is related with the packages configuration but I cannot find the problem. Here the configuration that I use (see section 6 that is where I load `hyperref` and `glossaries` packages):

```
    %****************************************************************************************************
% classicthesis-config.tex 
% formerly known as loadpackages.sty, classicthesis-ldpkg.sty, and classicthesis-preamble.sty 
% Use it at the beginning of your ClassicThesis.tex, or as a LaTeX Preamble 
% in your ClassicThesis.{tex,lyx} with \input{classicthesis-config}
% ****************************************************************************************************  
% If you like the classicthesis, then I would appreciate a postcard. 
% My address can be found in the file ClassicThesis.pdf. A collection 
% of the postcards I received so far is available online at 
% postcards [dot] miede [dot] de
% ****************************************************************************************************

% ****************************************************************************************************
% 1. Configure classicthesis for your needs here, e.g., remove "drafting" below 
% in order to deactivate the time-stamp on the pages
% ****************************************************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{
    eulerchapternumbers,
    listings,
    pdfspacing,
    linedheaders,
    subfig,
    beramono,
    eulermath,
    parts}{classicthesis}                                       
% ********************************************************************
% Available options for classicthesis.sty 
% (see ClassicThesis.pdf for more information):
% drafting
% parts nochapters linedheaders
% eulerchapternumbers beramono eulermath pdfspacing minionprospacing
% tocaligned dottedtoc manychapters
% listings floatperchapter subfig
% ********************************************************************

% ********************************************************************
% Triggers for this config
% ******************************************************************** 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{enable-backrefs} % enable backrefs in the bibliography
\setboolean{enable-backrefs}{true} % true false
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 2. Personal data and user ad-hoc commands
% ****************************************************************************************************
\newcommand{\myTitle}{Title\xspace}
\newcommand{\mySubtitle}{SubtitleRow1\\SubtitleRow2\\SubtitleRow3\\ SubtitleRow4\xspace}
\newcommand{\myDegree}{degree}
\newcommand{\myName}{name}
\newcommand{\myProf}{}
\newcommand{\myOtherProf}{}
\newcommand{\mySupervisor}{supervisor}
\newcommand{\myTutor}{tutor}
\newcommand{\myFaculty}{faculty}
\newcommand{\myDepartment}{department\xspace}
\newcommand{\myStudies}{\textsc{Computer science}\xspace}
\newcommand{\myUni}{University\xspace}
\newcommand{\myLocation}{City\xspace}
\newcommand{\myTime}{October 2013\xspace}
\newcommand{\myVersion}{version 0.1\xspace}

% ********************************************************************
% Setup, finetuning, and useful commands
% ********************************************************************
\newcounter{dummy} % necessary for correct hyperlinks (to index, bib, etc.)
\newlength{\abcd} % for ab..z string length calculation
\providecommand{\mLyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}
% ****************************************************************************************************

% ****************************************************************************************************
% 3. Loading some handy packages
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ******************************************************************** 
% Packages with options that might require adjustments
% ******************************************************************** 
\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8x}{inputenc}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\PassOptionsToPackage{round}{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib}
\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% ******************************************************************** 
% General useful packages
% ******************************************************************** 
\PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics
\usepackage{fontenc}                 
\usepackage{xspace} % to get the spacing after macros right  
\usepackage{mparhack} % get marginpar right
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % fixes some LaTeX stuff 
\PassOptionsToPackage{printonlyused,smaller}{acronym}
\usepackage{acronym} % nice macros for handling all acronyms in the thesis
\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{#1}\hfill} % fix the list of acronyms
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 4. Setup floats: tables, (sub)figures, and captions
% ****************************************************************************************************
\usepackage{tabularx} % better tables
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} % increase table row height
\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myfloatalign}{\centering} % to be used with each float for alignment
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=hang,font=small}
\usepackage{subfig}  
% ****************************************************************************************************

% ****************************************************************************************************
% 5. Setup code listings
% ****************************************************************************************************
\usepackage{listings} 
%\lstset{emph={trueIndex,root},emphstyle=\color{BlueViolet}}%\underbar} % for special keywords
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,%C++,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},%\bfseries,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    %identifierstyle=\color{NavyBlue},
    commentstyle=\color{Green}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    numbers=none,%left,%
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,%\tiny
    stepnumber=5,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=single,
    belowcaptionskip=.75\baselineskip
    %frame=L
} 
% ****************************************************************************************************    

% ****************************************************************************************************
% 6. PDFLaTeX, hyperreferences and citation backreferences
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Using PDFLaTeX
% ********************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}
    \usepackage{hyperref}  % backref linktocpage pagebackref
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1 
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex}{graphicx}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 

% ********************************************************************
% Setup the style of the backrefs from the bibliography
% (translate the options to any language you use)
% ********************************************************************
\newcommand{\backrefnotcitedstring}{\relax}%(Not cited.)
\newcommand{\backrefcitedsinglestring}[1]{(Cited on page~#1.)}
\newcommand{\backrefcitedmultistring}[1]{(Cited on pages~#1.)}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{enable-backrefs}}%
{%
        \PassOptionsToPackage{hyperpageref}{backref}
        \usepackage{backref} % to be loaded after hyperref package 
           \renewcommand{\backreftwosep}{ and~} % separate 2 pages
           \renewcommand{\backreflastsep}{, and~} % separate last of longer list
           \renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}  % disable standard
           \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{% detailed backref
              \ifcase #1 %
                 \backrefnotcitedstring%
              \or%
                 \backrefcitedsinglestring{#2}%
              \else%
                 \backrefcitedmultistring{#2}%
              \fi}%
}{\relax}    

% ********************************************************************
% Hyperreferences
% ********************************************************************
\hypersetup{%
    %draft, % = no hyperlinking at all (useful in b/w printouts)
    colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,%
    % uncomment the following line if you want to have black links (e.g., for printing)
    %colorlinks=false, linktocpage=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,% 
    breaklinks=true, pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,%
    plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,%
    hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O,%nesting=true,%frenchlinks,%
    urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=webgreen, %pagecolor=RoyalBlue,%
    %urlcolor=Black, linkcolor=Black, citecolor=Black, %pagecolor=Black,%
    pdftitle={\myTitle},%
    pdfauthor={\textcopyright\ \myName, \myUni, \myFaculty},%
    pdfsubject={},%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
% tikz figures
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
% To scale fonts
\usepackage{scalefnt}

% Package for analytic index
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

% Package for glossary (Glossaries)
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{Frontmatter/Glossaries}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: We load the `hyperref` package last of all. Ιs a known "weirdness" of `hyperref`

Comment: @karathan not in the case of glossaries. It is supposed to be loaded after hyperref. At least last time I checked the manual. Unfortunatelly the OP does not provide a minimal working example. Daniele, it would take a lot of effort to turn your example into a working example. I am not sure someone will be willing to put the work in. You are better off to make an working copy-paste-able example people can work of.

Comment: Please see [the steps outlined in this answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that#answer-3225) to make a _complete_ document that includes _only_ the packages that are needed to generate the error. Then it will be much more likely that someone can help.

Comment: @MartinH However ultimately the test proves the opposite ... I'm curious to see the outcome of this question.

Comment: Well no it does not. If you load package at a point where it has no effect on a second package then this proves nothing does it? The problem lies most certainly in some "funny business" this outdated template does as I know it is working under normal circumstances. I suspect the package `acronym` for starters just by browsing though the list of packages

Comment: The package list is hopelessly messy though. Many packages are loaded twice, `utf8x` encoding is used (should be `utf8`) and many many are loaded after `hyperref` which indeed can cause problems.